# Find and add to an associative array in an unknown multidimensional array

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array, key, associative-array

I am trying to create a self populating tree by adding arrays to arrays. What I am having trouble with is finding an associative key within the array and then adding new content to it (a new array).

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" before asking a question. Could you please add some code for what you have tried so far

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This could be done recursively. You can search for the key in the master array and merge that value[s] with the data you would like to append/insert.

Below I've created two functions that will achieve this.

```php
/** Append or create to an array searching for the index with the with the value $key. If $key is set to null, append to array using numerical index.
 * @param array $masterArray Array to append to
 * @param mixed $data
 * @param null  $key         If not set, will append to the master array
 */
function append($key, $data, &$masterArray) {
    if($key===null) {
        $masterArray[] = $data;
    } else if(!_appendHelper($key, $data, $masterArray)) {
        $masterArray[$key] = $data;
    }
}

/** Helper function to recursively search/merge array */
function _appendHelper($key, $data, &$masterArray) {
    foreach($masterArray as $k => &$v) {
        if($k===$key) {
            $v = array_merge($v, is_array($data) ? $data : [$data]);
            return true;
        } elseif(is_array($v)) {
            _appendHelper($key, $data, $v);
        }
    }
    return false; // Key does not exist
}


$masterArray = ['foo' => ['bar' => ['ram' => ['ewe' => []]]], ['man' => ['chu' => []]]];

append('foo', ['__TEST1__' => [1, 1, 1]], $masterArray);
print_r($masterArray);

append('new_key', ['__TEST2__' => [2, 2, 2]], $masterArray);
print_r($masterArray);

append(null, ['__TEST3__' => [3, 3, 3]], $masterArray);
print_r($masterArray);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I will not know the location or depth of the key. I need a way to search for the and then once it is found, add new stuff to it.

Comment: Can the keys exist on different levels? ie: `['foo'=>['foo'=>['foo'=>[1,2,...]]]`

Comment: Consider it more like: `['foo' => ['bar' => ['ram' => ['ewe' => [] ]]], ['man' => ['chu' =>[] ]]` but it can go on indefinatly. I need to beable to access any of those keys at any time and add to them.

Comment: @IanTelke I've updated my code to fit your last comment. I believe this is what you are looking for.